# ¿Qué es reflexión y por qué es útil?

Tags: java, reflection

¿Qué es la reflexión y por qué es útil?

Estoy particularmente interesado en Java, pero asumo que los principios son los mismos en cualquier idioma.

Pregunta original: [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

Desde el punto de vista conceptual, es la capacidad que tiene un programa de obtener información sobre su estructura (componentes que hacen parte del mismo: clases, tipos de datos, etc.) y además de actuar sobre la misma en tiempo de ejecución.

Es útil porque existen ocasiones donde esta información no es posible obtenerla en tiempo de compilación (por ejemplo el programa como tal puede estar compuesto de clases proporcionadas por componentes externos), además esto permite modificar el comportamiento del programa de acuerdo a las circunstancias de ejecución (por ejemplo crear clases o tipos de datos específicos del entorno donde se ejecuta).